# I am getting:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using Visual Studio Code. I am trying to set textContent property equal to var dice but it is showing error.
Here are my screenshots, please help me with it.
Also, same error occurs when i try to set addEventListener property.
My HTML code-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>DICE GAME</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\stylesheet\main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
<body class="container">
<section class="wrapper">
        <button class="btn-new" id="newgame">NEW GAME</button>
        <img src="dice-1.png" height="60px" width="60px" class="image" id="dice">
    <section class="col-1-2">
        <h1 id="player-0">PLAYER 1</h1>
        <h2 id="roundscore-0">40</h2>
    <div class="currentscore">
        <h3>Current Score</h3>
        <h4 id="Current-0">5</h4>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section class="col-1-2">
        <h1 id="player-1">PLAYER 2</h1>
        <h2 id="roundscore-1">54</h2>
    <div class="currentscore">
        <h3>Current Score</h3>
        <h4 id="Current-1">2</h4>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section>
            <button class="btn-roll">ROLL DICE</button>
            <button class="btn-hold">HOLD</button>
    </section>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript code-

````
scores = [0,0];
roundscore = 0;
activeplayer = 0;

dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

document.getElementById('Current-1').textContent = dice;```
````

Comment: it's in capital `c`

Comment: thanks @Sven.hig. But that's not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this tag at the bottom of body.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>DICE GAME</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\stylesheet\main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body class="container">
<section class="wrapper">
        <button class="btn-new" id="newgame">NEW GAME</button>
        <img src="dice-1.png" height="60px" width="60px" class="image" id="dice">
    <section class="col-1-2">
        <h1 id="player-0">PLAYER 1</h1>
        <h2 id="roundscore-0">40</h2>
    <div class="currentscore">
        <h3>Current Score</h3>
        <h4 id="Current-0">5</h4>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section class="col-1-2">
        <h1 id="player-1">PLAYER 2</h1>
        <h2 id="roundscore-1">54</h2>
    <div class="currentscore">
        <h3>Current Score</h3>
        <h4 id="Current-1">2</h4>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section>
            <button class="btn-roll">ROLL DICE</button>
            <button class="btn-hold">HOLD</button>
    </section>
</section>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you put this script code? (in head or top of body or bottom of body)

Comment: You should do as I told in my answer and check and let me know. I will help you.